# How to fix 'TypeError: invalid keyword argument for sort()'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

Order a list of 2-dimensional points using the `compare_points` function.

I don't understand how to pass the `compare_points` function to the `sort()` method.

```
def compare_points( p, q ):
    if p[0] < q[0] or (p[0] == q[0] and p[1] < q[1]):
        return -1
    elif p[0] > q[0] or (p[0] == q[0] and p[1] > q[1]):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

#print(compare_points( [1,3], [5,6])) # outputs -1
#print(compare_points( [1,3], [1,6])) # ouputs -1
#print(compare_points( [1,3], [1,3])) # outputs 0
#print(compare_points( [1,3], [0,3])) # outputs 1


L = [ [5,8], [5,2], [12, 3], [1,3], [10,2], [12,1], [12,3] ]
L.sort(cmp=compare_points)
print(L)
```

Actual results:

```
L.sort(cmp=compare_points)
builtins.TypeError: 'cmp' is an invalid keyword argument for sort()
```

Expected results:

```
L = [ [1,3], [5,2], [5,8], [10,2], [12,1], [12,3], [12,3] ]
```

Comment: The name of the argument is `key=`, not `cmp=`

Comment: @AndrejKesely: In Python-2.x there was a `cmp`, but that has been removed.

Comment: Comparison functions were removed in python 3

Answer (score 6):

There is actually no need at all here to specify a key, since what you define here, is basically just *lexicographical order*, which is the standard way a list is ordered in Python.

You thus can sort *without* specifying a key, like:

```
>>> L = [ [5,8], [5,2], [12, 3], [1,3], [10,2], [12,1], [12,3] ]
>>> L.sort()
>>> L
[[1, 3], [5, 2], [5, 8], [10, 2], [12, 1], [12, 3], [12, 3]]
```

In [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x), the [**`.sort(…)`** <sup>[python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html) function could indeed take a `cmp=...` parameter that was a comparator between two values. Since [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), this [parameter has been removed](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Sorting with a key is more effective, since it avoids that you implement a comparison function that is invalid: a comparison function should be *reflexive*, *antisymmetric*, and *transitive*. Some comparison functions did not meet those conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Python3
in python3, the keyword argument is key, so you should do

```
L.sort(key=compare_points)
```

If you want to do it with the cmp keyword argument, you should use Python2

Comment: Note, though, that `compare_points` isn't really a valid key function. You need to convert it first: `L.sort(key=functools.cmp_to_key(compare_points))`.

Comment: Python 3 didn't simply change the name of `cmp` to `key`; Python 2 had both, and Python 3 dropped support for `cmp` altogether.